# Proving subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know you need closure under addition and closure under scalar multiplication. But can you also prove something a subspace by claiming it spans the set and is linearly independent?

Comment: sorry, but as written this question is not clear at all. What is "it"? Spans what set?

Comment: for example, say W = (1,2,3). is it enough to say since it spans R3 and is linearly independent that makes it a subspace of R3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The set $\{1\}$ is linearly independent and spans the one dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}$ but it isn't a subspace.

In general, what you have described is a *basis*. A basis is never a subspace since (at the very least) a basis can't contain the $0$ vector and a subspace must.